# (failed) ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES requests in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, headers, tracking

The page makes about 40 navigator.sendBeacon() calls to the same endpoint during and before rendering of the body, but sometimes a number of them result in a failed request with timing as "stalled".

I think I need to refactor the code and maybe queue the stringified objects and call sendBeacon() at a less busier timing, but I have no idea how

Thanks in advance!

The called function is

```
const fireAway = obj => {
  obj.hostname = _domain
  obj.referrer = _referrer
  obj.isMobile = _isMobile
  navigator.sendBeacon(_endpoint, JSON.stringify(obj))
}
```

Comment: I think you should post this question to https://stackoverflow.com. SuperUser is more about computer/software/hardware issue, but it's not about software development question.

Comment: We ran into a similar issue and filed a bug with the Chromium project:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=958108